# Why is the computer's input not being considered?

Tags: c, performance, output

In the code below there is an error I can't locate causing the computer's selection to not be accounted for. The user's input is being considered in the Nim game yet the computer's pieces are not being subtracted.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printInstructions();
int getUserInput(int);
int randomRange(int,int);
int PlayerTurn(int);
int smartCompMove(int);
int dumbCompMove(int);

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int pieceAmount = randomRange(12,24);
    char smartCompOrDumb;
    printf("Do you want to play a smart computer or a dumb one? Select 'S' or 'D'.");
    scanf("%c",&smartCompOrDumb);
    bool gameOver = false;
    bool playerTurn = true;
    printInstructions();

    while(pieceAmount > 0 && gameOver == false)
    {
        if (playerTurn == false)
        {
            if(pieceAmount <= 4)
            {
                printf("\nThe Computer has won :P  ");
                gameOver = true;
                exit(0);
            }
            if (smartCompOrDumb == 's' || smartCompOrDumb == 'S')
            {
                playerTurn = true;
                pieceAmount = smartCompMove(pieceAmount);
                printf("%d",pieceAmount);
            }
            else if (smartCompOrDumb == 'd' || smartCompOrDumb == 'D')
            {
                playerTurn = true;
                pieceAmount = dumbCompMove(pieceAmount);
                printf("%d",pieceAmount);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(pieceAmount <= 4)
            {
                printf("\nYou have won :)  ");
                gameOver = true;
                exit(0);
            }
            playerTurn = false;
            pieceAmount = PlayerTurn(pieceAmount);
            printf("%d",pieceAmount);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void printInstructions()
{
    printf("\nThis game is called Nim and it is thousands of years old.");
    printf("\nTake turns picking one to three pieces from a pile and whomever picks the last piece wins.");
    printf("\n__________________________________________________________________________________________");
}

int randomRange(int low,int high)
{
    return rand()% (high - low) + low;
}

int PlayerTurn(int pieceAmount)
{
    pieceAmount = getUserInput(pieceAmount);
    return pieceAmount;
}

int getUserInput(int pieceAmount)
{
    int userInput = 0;
    bool flag = true;

    while (flag == true)
    {
        if (pieceAmount > 4)
        {
            printf("\nThere are %d pieces remaining.\n",pieceAmount);
            printf("\nHow many pieces do you want to select? ");
            scanf("%d", &userInput);
            if (userInput >= 1 && userInput < 5)
            {
                pieceAmount = pieceAmount - userInput;
                flag = false; 
            }
            else
            {
                printf("This is not a valid move so try again.");
            }
        }
    }
    return pieceAmount;
}

int dumbCompMove(int pieceAmount)
{
    int dumbPick = rand() % 3 + 1;
    printf("\nComputer will pick from the stack. \n");
    pieceAmount = pieceAmount - dumbPick;
    printf("\nComputer picked %d pieces. \n", dumbPick );
    return pieceAmount;
}

int smartCompMove(int pieceAmount)
{
    int smartPick = 1;
    printf("\nThe computer will select their pieces. \n");
    if (pieceAmount >= 15 && pieceAmount < 24)
    {
      smartPick = 2;
      pieceAmount = pieceAmount - smartPick;
    }
    else if (pieceAmount >= 10 && pieceAmount < 15)
    {
      smartPick = 4;
      pieceAmount = pieceAmount - smartPick;
    }     
    else if (pieceAmount >= 6 && pieceAmount < 10)
    {
      smartPick = 1;
      pieceAmount = pieceAmount -smartPick;
    }
    else
        pieceAmount = 3;
        printf("\nThe computer selected %d pieces. \n",smartPick);
        return pieceAmount;
}
```

I had this code working earlier yet somehow I must have altered something minor and now it will not function properly. I am using the Cloud9 program to run it.

Comment: Your code runs just fine for me (I won!) when compiling with GCC 5.4. Although you should `#include <time.h>`, as you get a warning that you're implicitly using `time()` on line 14.

Comment: At first glance, this shouldn't work.  The variable pieceAmount isn't global but is used in most of the functions?  Nevermind, after a second glance, it will work, but can be confusing to re-use the same name locally.

Comment: What does "will not function properly" actually mean?

Comment: What is the input? What is the output? What is the desired output? What is not considered? Please describe more about what happens unexpectedly or fails to happen though expected. Have a look at [ask].

Comment: the last `else` in the program has the next 3 lines indented, as if they are part of the else code block.  If they are part of the `else` code block, then a set of braces '{' ...'}' is missing.  If only the first following line is part of the `else` code block, then (for readability by us humans) the next two lines should not be indented